# Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements,,,

Tags: objective-c, loader, verification, codesign

When i try to build my application for archive and try send by Application Loader i get this:

`warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains   disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)
Executable=/Users/tomkowz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pertcalculator-ctqojevgktdyusdypszrwaabqxyr/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/pertcalculator.app/pertcalculator
codesign_wrapper-4.1: using Apple CA for profile evaluation
/Users/tomkowz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pertcalculator-ctqojevgktdyusdypszrwaabqxyr/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/pertcalculator.app: valid on disk
/Users/tomkowz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pertcalculator-ctqojevgktdyusdypszrwaabqxyr/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/pertcalculator.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
test-requirement: code failed to satisfy specified code requirement(s)
codesign_wrapper-4.1: failed to execute codesign(1)
 - (null)`

how can i solve it? i try send this up half of the day  : /

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer:

Don't forget about creating Distribution Profile when you create Developer Profile in ADC.
Dont' forget check Release in Edit Scheme of Your Build Scheme.